# NGINX strict redirect

Tags: nginx, url, redirect

I have a URL:

```
https://www.example.com/catalog
```

I want to access it via:

```
https://www.example.com/products
```

If I redirect this url, then when I try to follow the url:

```
https://www.example.com/products/bicycle
https://www.example.com/products/car
https://www.example.com/products/tshirt
etc..
```

That brings me back:

```
https://www.example.com/products
```

**How can I redirect ONLY [www.example.com/catalog](http://www.example.com/catalog) to ONLY the [www.example.com/products](http://www.example.com/products) url?**

I tried to do:

```
        location /products/ {
        return 301 /catalog/;
        }
```

and:

```
rewrite /products/ /catalog/ permanent;
```

and:

```
       if ($is_args = '') {
       rewrite ^/catalog\$ /products permanent;
       }
```

*It redirects me from /products/ to /catalog/ as I wanted. But if I go to other url /products/car /products/tshirt/ /products/bicycle and the like, then I am also transferred to /catalog, but I don’t need it.*
Help me please.

My config file:

```
server {
        server_name sub.url.ru;
        root   /home/suburl/public_html/;
        index index.php;

        access_log /home/sportmen/sportmen.ru/logs/access.log;
        error_log /home/sportmen/sportmen.ru/logs/error.log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on; }
        if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)/index.(html|php)) { return 301 $1/$is_args$args; }
        location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php$is_args$args;  }
        location ~* @.*\.html$ { internal; }
        include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/suburl/redirect.conf;

        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/suburl/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/suburl/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


###phpMyadmin###

        location /phpmy123 {
        alias /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        }
        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        access_log    off;
        log_not_found    off;
        expires 1M;
        }
}
        location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
}
###end-phpMyAdmin###
server {

        if ($host = sub.url.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        server_name sub.url.ru;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
location /products/ {
    return 301 /catalog/;
}
```

Here `/product/` is interpreted as a prefix. For nginx to interpret it as exact match, you need to use a modifier, e.g. `=` :

```
location = /products/ {
    return 301 /catalog/;
}
```

Here `/product/bicycle` is no longer a match for this location.

See other location modifiers here : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#locations

Comment: This helped me, but if I specify, 
`location /products {
    return 301 /catalog/;
}`
then I can only follow this link in the browser without the slash / (example.com/products )
If I point my browser to example.com/products/ I get a 404 error.
How can I make it so that I can follow the link with and without a slash?